# Unable to Update Numpy from 1.6.1 to 1.8.0

Tags: python, numpy, updates

I am trying to update numpy and scipy at the moment.  I am consistently returning this error when follow the directions at [scipy.org](http://scipy.org) and use `sudo pip install numpy --upgrade`.

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -latlas
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
error: Command "gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-Bsy       
mbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/numpy/core/blasdot/_       
dotblas.o -L/usr/local/lib -Lbuild/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7 -lf77blas -lcblas 
-latlas -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/numpy/core/_dotblas.so" failed with exit 
status 1
```

I have tried to get the packages `-lf77blas -lcblas -latlas -o` with `sudo apt-get install latlas`.  I consistently get a return of `E: Unable to locate package`.

I am running Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.2.0-23-generic x86_64), Python 2.7, Numpy 1.6, and Scipy 0.9.0, and GCC 4.6.3.  Thanks in advance for your help.

**Full Error Message**

This is the full error message that when I try `pip`

```
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/local/lib/libf77blas.a when searching for -lf77blas
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/local/lib/libf77blas.a when searching for -lf77blas

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lf77blas

/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/local/lib/libcblas.a when searching for -lcblas
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/local/lib/libcblas.a when searching for -lcblas

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcblas

/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/local/lib/libatlas.a when searching for -latlas
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/local/lib/libatlas.a when searching for -latlas
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -latlas

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/local/lib/libf77blas.a when searching for -lf77blas
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/local/lib/libf77blas.a when searching for -lf77blas

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lf77blas

/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/local/lib/libcblas.a when searching for -lcblas
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/local/lib/libcblas.a when searching for -lcblas

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcblas

/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/local/lib/libatlas.a when searching for -latlas
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/local/lib/libatlas.a when searching for -latlas

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -latlas

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
error: Command "gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/numpy/core/blasdot/_dotblas.o -L/usr/local/lib -Lbuild/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7 -lf77blas -lcblas -latlas -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/numpy/core/_dotblas.so" failed with exit status 1
```

Comment: The package you want for `atlas` is called `libatlas-dev`: `sudo apt-get install libatlas-dev`

Comment: How about posting that as an answer, @DanD.?

Comment: @DanD. Thanks for sharing.  Installing `libatlas-dev` did not change result.

Comment: Is there a specific location in need to run `sudo apt-get install libatlas-dev`?

Comment: Did you try to compile ATLAS yourself?

Comment: After installing `libatlas-dev` and following [this post](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/52703/using-atlas-from-scipy), my issue was resolved and I am now using the latest numpy and scipy.  Thanks for your help all.